# how to count periods latters in string python

Tags: python, string

i need to count how many periods (points) appear in a string.

for example:

```
str="hellow.my.word."
```

the code should return 3.

I tried to use the following function but it returns the length of the string.

```
 num=str.count('.')
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Other answers that I have seen appear to use iterations. Using iterations is not appropriate for this purpose. Use regular expressions instead: `len(re.findall("(\.)", my_string))`

Answer (score 2):

Use variable name other than `str(str is built-in).`

Secondly:

```
string = "hellow.my.word."
num=string.count('.') # num=3 ...THIS WORKS
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a for comprehension to iterate over the string:

Also, don't use `str` as a variable name, it's a built-in function in python.

```
string="hellow.my.word."

sum([char == '.' for char in string])  # Returns 3
```

**EDIT**

Regarding @niemmi's comment, apparently this is possible using `string.count('symbol')`:

```
string.count('.') # returns 3
```

Docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.count

Comment: FWIW, although `str` is certainly a callable it's not really a function. `str` is a type (IOW, a class), so when you call it it creates a new string instance.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to filter out other characters than `.` and measure the length of resulting list:

```
len([1 for c in string if c == '.'])
```